# Finding the inverse of a recursive function?

Tags: recurrence-relations, inverse

Let's say I have this function $$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{x-1}f(i)$$ provided $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1$ and $x \in \mathbb Z$. This function is evidently one-to-one on $[3, \infty) $. Is there an inverse to this and if yes, how to find it?
Thanks in advance.

PS. If you see something wrong please write it in the comments. I will take action ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the recursion to compute the values of $f(x)$ for a few small values of $x$:

$f(2) = 1$, $f(3) = 2$, $f(4) = 4$, $f(5) = 8$, $f(6) = 16$, etc.

Do you see a pattern? (Think powers of $2$) This will give you a formula for $f(x)$ valid for $x \ge 2$.

As you said, the function is one-to-one on $[3,\infty)$, so it must have an inverse on $[3,\infty)$.

To invert this function, simply set $x = f(y)$ and solve for $y$.

Comment: So the only way of finding an inverse to a recursive function is to just compute the values and look for a pattern?

Comment: @SalmonKiller Given that recursive functions are *all* [computable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function), you may imagine there is a whole lot of complicated cases. Are you asking for a general procedure for ivnersion? There is simply no such thing. So basically yes, you have to find some pattern.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut OK. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Another option is to note that $f(x+1)-f(x) = f(x)$, and so, $f(x+1) = 2f(x)$. While there is no way to come up with a closed form solution to every recursion, this recursion is linear with constant coefficients. There are generalized methods to solve these types of recursions.